# How to Get User Information By Different User ID in Stored Procedure my Query Attached?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

what i wanna do that i am passing id to SP then my query get uder Id's Against it my query is given below,

```
select RequestFrom from UserReqest where RequestTo=10 and IsApprove=0

select * from user where user_ID= (i have to use all five id's here ?)
```

as i pass "10" to sp and it will get five different id against id "10" then how would i get data of all those 5 id ? how would i implement it ? i have to use loop ? i need suggestion...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
select * from user where user_ID in
(
    select RequestFrom from UserReqest where RequestTo=10 and IsApprove=0
)
```